# value covers pervious value using append() in python

Tags: python

i am trying to make a nested list using append function, but the last value will recover pervious values, anyone can tell me why, and how to do it correctly. 
thanks

```
d= []
temp = [0,0,0]
for i in range(4):
   temp[0] = i+1
   d.append(temp)
```

the output shows:

> [[4, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0]]

but the output that i want is

> [[1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0]]

Answer (score 1):

Your resultant list is `[temp, temp, temp, temp]`.  If you want the objects to be different, you'll have to make a new sub-list every time.  One easy way, using a list comprehension, would be

```
d = [[i, 0, 0] for i in range(1, 5)]
```

Comment: Alternatively, use the OP's code, and just change `d.append(temp)` to `d.append(temp[:])`, using the "empty slice" to insert a shallow copy of `temp` each time, not another alias to it. Your list comprehension is faster and clearer about what it's doing, shallow copying is just the minimal fix.

Comment: thank you very much for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
d= []
temp = [0,0,0]
for i in range(4):
   tmp = [t for t in temp]
   tmp[0] = i+1
   d.append(tmp)
```

Comment: `[t for t in temp]` is a rather verbose/slow way to say `temp[:]`. A no-op listcomp is always better as the empty slice, `someseq[:]`, or if the input might not be a `list` and the output must be a `list`, `list(someseq)`.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: you are welcome